# Wordpress PHP version won't change from 5.2

Tags: php

I have inherited the care of a WordPress site. It was running on PHP 5.2. I copied it to a development environment to make some changes. The development server is running PHP 7.2.

However, the site still appeared to be running PHP 5.2.

I used `AddHandler` to set the PHP version to 7.2 in the .htaccess file in the site root. I then tested it with `phpinfo()`, which showed PHP 7.2.

However, the WordPress installation is still operating on PHP 5.2. I have searched for any rouge .htaccess or .ini files, looked for modified core files, reviewed plugins, etc.

I have used grep but came up with nothing. If anyone has experienced this or can recommend a course of action It would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed PHP 7.x on the live server (or requested that the hosting company do so)? That's something that's outside the scope of WordPress—it's a server issue, not a WordPress issue.

Comment: @PatJ I have not made any changes to the live server. I am experiencing this problem on the development server. The development server is using mod_hive to provide multiple PHP versions for testing. PHP 7.0, 7.1, and 7.2 are all available.